# JavaScript - default values in destructured object passed to arrow function as an argument

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, arguments, arrow-functions, destructuring

```
const f = ({ a: a = 0, b: b = 1 }) => { ... }
```

I'm looking for an explanaition to why this doesn't work when I call `f()` and it does when I call `f({})`.

**Main question:** Is it possible to have an arrow function with destructured object passed as an argument, with it's properties being given default values if not defined?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`undefined` is no object.

You could use a default object as well.

```js
const f = ({ a = 0, b = 1 } = {}) => { console.log(a, b) };

f();
```